# Akamai fast purge using php 5.3

Tags: php, php-5.3, akamai

How to clear Akamai cache using php 5.3?
The code provided in Akamai Github for php 5.6+ is working. But the code provided in Akamai Github page for php 5.3 is giving error.

The errors lines are marked as ‘//’:

> require_once 'src/Authentication.php';
>   require_once 'src/Authentication/Timestamp.php';
>   require_once 'src/Authentication/Nonce.php';
>   require_once 'src/Exception/ConfigException.php';
>   //Fatal error: Class 'Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Exception' not found in \src\Exception\ConfigException.php on line 22 require_once 'src/Exception/SignerException/InvalidSignDataException.php'‌​;
>   //Fatal error: Class 'Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Exception\SignerException' not found in \src\Exception\SignerException\InvalidSignDataException.php on line 22

Comment: What error? Please show your code.

Comment: The errors lines are marked as ‘//’
`require_once 'src/Authentication.php';
require_once 'src/Authentication/Timestamp.php';
require_once 'src/Authentication/Nonce.php';
require_once 'src/Exception/ConfigException.php';
//Fatal error: Class 'Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Exception' not found in \src\Exception\ConfigException.php on line 22
require_once 'src/Exception/SignerException/InvalidSignDataException.php';
//Fatal error: Class 'Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Exception\SignerException' not found in \src\Exception\SignerException\InvalidSignDataException.php on line 22

Comment: Put the details in the question.

Comment: I suspect you didn't properly install the library.

Comment: It would also help if you provide a link to the github code you're using.

Comment: I guess this is what you're talking about? https://github.com/akamai-open/AkamaiOPEN-edgegrid-php

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am using the method mentioned in url. The error had gone after including
require_once 'src/Exception.php';
require_once 'src/Exception/SignerException.php';
What is the next step ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two exceptions missing from the `require` block:

```php
require_once 'src/Exception.php';
require_once 'src/Exception/SignerException.php';
```

Adding these should fix the issue.

The full code block to purge you would use:

```php
$auth = \Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Authentication::createFromEdgeRcFile('ccuv3', './.edgerc');
$auth->setHttpMethod('POST');
$auth->setPath('/ccu/v3/invalidate/url');

$body = json_encode(array(
    'hostname' => 'example.org',
    'objects' => array('/path/to/object', '/path/to/other/object')
));

$auth->setBody($body);

$context = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => array(
            'Authorization: ' . $auth->createAuthHeader(),
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body),
        ),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $body
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($context);

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://' . $auth->getHost() . $auth->getPath(), null, $context));
```

Better yet, would be to wrap this up in a function:

```php
function fastPurge($hostname, array $objects)
{
    $body = json_encode(array(
        'hostname' => $hostname,
        'objects' => $objects
    ));

    $auth = \Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Authentication::createFromEdgeRcFile('ccuv3', './.edgerc');
    $auth->setHttpMethod('POST');
    $auth->setPath('/ccu/v3/invalidate/url');
    $auth->setBody($body);

    $context = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => array(
                'Authorization: ' . $auth->createAuthHeader(),
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body),
            ),
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $body
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($context);

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://' . $auth->getHost() . $auth->getPath(), null, $context));
}

// Call the fastPurge function
fastPurge('example.org', array('/path/to/object', '/path/to/other/object'));
```

Comment: @modellita I have updated the answer to include the full CCUv3 fast purge call.